# How to increase frame rate of webcam's video input? Emgu CV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, frame-rate

I'm using emgu CV & C# and getting low FPS (approx. 8fps) while capturing/displaying webcam video! so far this is what I have tried:
I have to apply some filters as well, how can I make my code more efficient?
is there any way to process these frames using GPU?

```
    private Capture _capture;
    private bool _captureInProgress;
    private Image<Bgr, Byte> frame;
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
        captureImageBox.Image = frame;

    }

    private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (_capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                _capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;

        if (_capture != null)
        {
            if (_captureInProgress)
            {
                //stop the capture

                startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Start";
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //start the capture
                startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this : http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2602 ?

Comment: Yes! but it didn't work! :/

Comment: @Umair is it still an issue? the code you posted seems do nothing but getting the frame from the webcam without any further processing. could you post more code and the type of your webcam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're processing frames on the Application.Idle callback, which is only invoked every so often. Replace this line

`Application.Idle += ProcessFrame`

with

`_capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame`

and it should work. This callback is invoked every time a frame is available.

Comment: shouldn't it be _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame?

Comment: This did not work for me.  ProcessFrame was never called and my program just sat there.